# Clicking a button in JavaScript page - Selenium/Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, click

My code accesses a page, and I am trying to click on the button that says "Physician Program" on the menu list. If you click on this on the ***browser***, it directs you to a new webpage.

However, there is no href on the html of the page that would help me find this link via code (I am assuming because it is JavaScript?) Currently, I just used its Xpath.

My question is - If I am able to click on it in a browser, shouldnt I be able to click on it using Selenium? If so, how can this be done?

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.kidney.org/spring-clinical/program')
time.sleep(6)
page_source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')
element1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dx-c7ad8807-6124-b55e-d292-29a4389dee8e"]/div')
element1.click()
```

Comment: If you can successfully use xpath to locate the button, then what is the problem?

Comment: also why is it a webelement instead of android or mobilelement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

import subprocess
#other imports
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.kidney.org/spring-clinical/program')
time.sleep(6)
page_source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')
frame= WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.NAME, "SCM20 Advanced Practitioner Program")))
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
options = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(
    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class="track-selector-popup"] [role="option"]')))

options[0].click()

input()
```

Element is inside iframe so switch to it and also use waits, to switch back and interact with elements outside the frame use:

```
  driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: Thanks, what is iFrame and how did you find the "SCM20 Advanced Practitioner Program" is this within the inspect section of the HTML? Can i find the other options within here?

Comment: That is the name property of the element with tag name iframe , iframe creates a ln isolated frame inside your webpage

Comment: I am right clicking on the webpage and hitting inspect, and I cannot find what you found? I want to be able to do this to other options (pharmacist program etc)

Comment: Just use options[2].click and so on to choose respective option

Comment: Just scroll backward and see the parent of pharmacist program , you can see there is a element called iframe as a parent

Answer (score 2):

The element is inside iframe you need to switch to iframe

```
driver.switch_to.frame("SCM20 Advanced Practitioner Program")
element1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='Physician Program']")
element1.click()
```

Ideally you should use `webdriverwait` and wait for frame to be available.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,"SCM20 Advanced Practitioner Program"))) 
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH "//div[text()='Physician Program']"))).click()
```

You need to import below libraries

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: Thanks, what is iFrame and how did you find the "SCM20 Advanced Practitioner Program" is this within the inspect section of the HTML? Can i find the other options within here?